# How can I query for keyboard input in a GUI app without using a pre-built input form?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, maui

In a console app, I could put `Console.ReadKey()` in an infinite loop, and I have what I wanted. But how can I do that in a GUI app?

Let's say I'm using the new MAUI framework and I want to implement a text box from scratch. How could I query for user input? Since I'm reinventing a text form, the first step is to receive continuous, key-by-key input.

In a game engine, like Unity, you're given an input class, and you could check if and which key was pressed every frame. What's a .NET equivalent?

Comment: Text boxes in UI frameworks usually "listen" to low level keyboard events (key down, key up) when they are in focus, and interpret the relevant user input for the text box.

Comment: @wohlstad Yeah, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Does C#/.NET provide direct access to those events?

Comment: I am not an expert in this area. Found this searching for MAUI and keyboard events: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3858.

Comment: @wohlstad Thank you. Key-up and key-down are the mechanisms used in game engines, but I didn't think UI frameworks did the same thing. Now that you told me, I searched for "keyboard events" and "keyboard listeners" and found plenty of resources.

Comment: Wait for your good news! @verified_tinker